# Yarn seems to not download all files of a package

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependencies, yarnpkg, exceljs

I run into an odd problem. We have 3 microservices in our project, and all of them are using exceljs lib.
In two of them, yarn does download all the needed files of this package.
In the third one, it is missing the dist/es5/doc folder.
Version is exactly the same, records in yarn.lock are exactly the same across all three repos.
I even tried adding this lib to another project and it installed everything, but still in this one project it lacks doc folder... I have already tried using `yarn cache clean`, `rm -rf node_modules` and `yarn` again. Tried installing other specific versions, but without luck.
I have even tried installing deps with npm, and to my surprise npm installed the whole package, but unfortunately I can't switch from yarn.
I'm running out of ideas now, and couldn't find a similar issue.
Any ideas will be more than welcomed!

Comment: What happens if you cut ***everything*** out of the `package.json` for this problematic project except this one package? Same deal?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Just cut out all other packages from deps and devdeps and issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get to solve the problem - it was .yarnclean fault. We had there 'doc' placed.
If you encounter problem alike, check this one :D